# Python - sum of squares

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to construct a piece of code that returns whether a number in range(1, limit) is a sum of two square numbers (square numbers such as `1**2 = 1`, `2**2 = 4` - so i'm trying to assign to a list of numbers whether they are a summed combination of ANY of those squared numbers - e.g. 1+1, 1+4, 4+16 etc). Below is what I have written, but it's returning "Not squared" for all values, which is wrong. I think there's probably one small element wrong with the code, but I'm pretty new to this and am struggling to see what it is. I would be extremely grateful for any guidance.

Code:

```
for n in range(1,21):
    lst = range(1,21)
    squares = [x**2 for x in lst]
    for i in range(1, 21):
        for x in range(1, 21):
            if i in squares:
                if x in squares:
                    n2 = i+x
    if n2 == n:
        print n, " - Sum of Squares"

    else:
        print n, " - Not a Sum of Squares"
```

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do you compare n with the last value of n2 computeted you should do

```
for n in range(1,21):
    lst = range(1,21)
    squares = [x**2 for x in lst]
    sum_of_squares = False
    for i in range(1, 21):
        for x in range(1, 21):
            if i in squares:
                if x in squares:
                    n2 = i+x
                    if n2 == n:
                        sum_of_square = True
    if sum_of_square:
        print n, " - Sum of Squares"
    else:
        print n, " - Not a Sum of Squares"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the original one::: But it might give your more insight.

```
In [20]: from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

In [21]: nk=map(sum,(combinations_with_replacement([x**2 for x in range(1,21)],2)))

In [22]: for n in range(1,21):
    ...:     if n in nk:
    ...:         print n, " -Sum of Squares"
    ...:     else:
    ...:         print n, " -Not a sum of Squares"
    ...:         
1  -Not a sum of Squares
2  -Sum of Squares
3  -Not a sum of Squares
4  -Not a sum of Squares
5  -Sum of Squares
6  -Not a sum of Squares
7  -Not a sum of Squares
8  -Sum of Squares
9  -Not a sum of Squares
10  -Sum of Squares
11  -Not a sum of Squares
12  -Not a sum of Squares
13  -Sum of Squares
14  -Not a sum of Squares
15  -Not a sum of Squares
16  -Not a sum of Squares
17  -Sum of Squares
18  -Sum of Squares
19  -Not a sum of Squares
20  -Sum of Squares

In [23]:
```

Comment: This isn't giving the correct output-- 8 is the sum of 4 + 4 and therefore is a sum of squares. Same with 1 + 1 = 2.

Comment: @ken.ganong: Aaah... it should be `combinations_with_replacement`; not just  `combinations`. Check the updated post.

Comment: @Namit, Yep, that looks better. +1

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```
for n in range(1,21):
    lst = range(1,21)
    squares = [x**2 for x in lst]
    for i in range(1, 21):
        for x in range(1, 21):
            if i in squares:
                if x in squares:
                    n2 = i+x
                    if n2 == n:
                        print n, " - Sum of Squares"

                    else:
                        print n, " - Not a Sum of Squares"
```

Output:

```
>>> 
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
1  - Not a Sum of Squares
2  - Sum of Squares
2  - Not a Sum of Squares
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be easier to generate all the numbers that are a sum of squares.

```
# oversized output array so we can use the numbers in 1..21 as indices
is_ssq = [False for n in range(22)]
squares = [x * x for x in range(1, 21)]
for i in squares:
    for x in squares:
        if i + x < 21:
            is_ssq[i + x] = True
```

So `is_ssq[n]` indicates if `n` is the sum of two squares.

---

If you want to get all Pythonic, you could use `itertools` and save an indent level:

```
import itertools

is_ssq = [False for n in range(22)]
squares = [x * x for x in range(1, 21)]
for i, x in itertools.product(squares, squares):
    if i + x < 21:
        is_ssq[i + x] = True
```